# Make data available on the spot with dataset API of tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two tensorflow datasets implemented by the following:

```
dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.rand(10000000))
dataset2 = dataset1.filter(lambda x: x<0.00001)
```

if I do :

```
for elem in dataset2:
    print(elem.numpy())
```

I will get the correct output, but it will be very long to be generated. Indeed, each elem of dataset1 is passed through the filter to see if it belongs to dataset2.
The thing is I would like to do this operation before-hand, meaning that I can wait for the whole dataset2 to be generated, potentially a long time, but then I want then to be able to grab elements from dataset2 without having to wait for the filtering. More precisely, I would like to do the filtering operation eagerly.

I hope I am being clear, thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30653), there is no eager execution in `tf.data`. As a result, in order to evaluate the whole dataset before iteration, you can use `tf.py_function` with a custom filter function as follows:

```
def custom_filter(x):
    if x < 0.00001:
        return x.numpy()
    else:
        return -1

dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.rand(10000000))
dataset2 = dataset1.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(custom_filter, [x], np.float32))

for elem in dataset2:
    print(elem.numpy())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't think it is convenient for me. 
Indeed, I could for example go over the whole dataset1 and put each elem that is filtered by the following :
`elem_list = []
for elem in dataset1:
     if elem.numpy<0.00001:
         elem_list.append[elem.numpy()]
dataset2=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(elem_list)`

Saying it, I guess I can use this solution...